# I am trying to develop a program that arranges my message(String) in a x*width matrix

Tags: c, arrays

For example(if width=5)
This a a C program.
This and " " should be in the 1st line and rest will go to the next line and so on.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int width;
    int i;
    char message[256];

    scanf("%d",&width);
    scanf(" %s",&message);
    for( i = 1; i <= width; i++ )
    {
        if( i == width )
        {
            printf( "\n" );
        }
        else
        {
            printf( "%s", message );
            i == width;
        }
    }
    printf( "\n" );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: It's unclear what you are trying to do or what the problem is, but usually a `for` loop will start from `0` like this `for(i=0; i<width; i++)` if the intention is to index the array you input to. Please add (by editing the question itself) an example of the two inputs you give, and the result you are expecting.

Comment: Arranging in a matrix suggests storage in a matrix data structure; you simply be trying to display it in a grid of the specified width.  Homework?

Comment: The second `i == width;` is a conditional test, whose result you don't use. Even if you intended `i = width;` that will force the `for` loop to end, so I wonder why the loop is there at all.

Answer (score 1):

Using `scanf` for input of a string containing spaces is arcane and over-complex since it normaly uses whitespace as a string delimiter - you will only get the first word of the "message".

You need to iterate the *length* of the string rather than the width of the "matrix" - otherwise it will just stop after one line.  You simply insert a newline every `width` characters.

The body of your loop makes little sense either since you just print `message` (several times) regardless of its length.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int width = 0 ;
    int i = 0 ;
    char message[256] = "" ;

    scanf( "%d", &width );
    fgets( message, sizeof(message), stdin ) ;

    while( message[i] != '\0' )
    {
        putchar( message[i] ) ;
        i++ ;
        if( i % width == 0 )
        {
            putchar( '\n' ) ;
        }
    }

    putchar( '\n' ) ;
}
```

In most circumstances some validity checking of the user input would be in order.

Comment: @WeatherVane :  fixed.